# installanywhere redirect debug logs to file

Tags: debugging, installanywhere

For debugging the Installanywhere created applications, I use

**export LAX_DEBUG=true**

then I run my installer as

**./setup.sh -DDEBUG=console**

which redirects all the debug logs to console. 
Can I redirect this logs to any file so that I can mention as:

**./setup.sh -DDEBUG=/tmp/a.txt**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installanywhere put all logs to -log.log file in installation directory chosen by user. 
To have additional entries in that file, you need to use CustomError class with appendMessage and appendError apis.