# Installanywhere for internationalization

Tags: java, internationalization, installanywhere

I am using InstallAnywhere to install and uninstall my product. 
It works perfectly fine with English language, but with german language it just stops in between.

Any idea why this might happen? 
how to know which action is occurring, when I click uninstall icon 
Thank you

Logs show this

```
Error running install panel: My Company Enterprise deinstallieren
    java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ZeroGdd.dispose(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.w(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.m(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.d(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.j(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ZeroGdd.dispose(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.w(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.d(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.d(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.actionPerformed(DashoA10*..)
        at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
        at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Read this about setting the debug setting then post extra details here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036425/installanywhere-redirect-debug-logs-to-file

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is that you can start the installer with console open to look for exceptions. Just start the installer with CTRL key down on your keyboard to view the Console window.